# How can we set options in select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two drop-down in my ui page. The second drop-down is generated when I select the first one.Here is my html code

```
  <td width="100"><label for="type">Menu Category Name:</label></td>
        <td width="200">
            <select name="type" id="type" class="target dropdown required"  onchange = getSubCategory(); tabindex="3" >
                <?php echo $typeOption;?>
            </select>
        </td>


<tr height="50">    
        <td width="100"><label for="sub_type">Menu Sub Category Name:</label></td>
        <td width="200">
            <select name="sub_type" id="sub_type" class="sub dropdown required" tabindex="3" >

            </select>
        </td>

    <tr height="50">
```

And my getSubCategory() function is

```
function getSubCategory(){
alert($("#type").val());
var catId = $("#type").val();
ajax(url,{id:catId,action:"getAllSubcategory"},function (response){
    $("div.sub").val(response);

});
```

}

and this is my backend php code.Here I am setting every option

```
function getAllSubcategory(){
global $db;
$data = $_REQUEST;
$getProductSubType = "SELECT id, name FROM cp_reference_master WHERE active = 'Y' 
                   AND mode='item_type_subcat'AND parent_id = '".$data['id']."' ORDER BY name ASC";
$resultType = $db->func_query($getProductSubType);

$subTypeOption = '<option value="">Select Category</option>';
$subTypeList = array();
if(is_array($resultType) && count($resultType)>0){
    foreach($resultType as $key => $details){
        $subTypeOption .= '<option value="'.$details['id'].'">'.$details['name'].'</option>';
        $subTypeList[$details['id']] = $details['name'];
    }
}
 return $subTypeOption;
```

}

I need to set the response to my subcategory select tag. I am unable to set the same. What is wrong in my code. I have tried 2 or 3 solutions already.

Comment: What is your response right now?? & How do you call `getAllSubcategory()` PHP function within the script??

Comment: <option value="">Select Category</option><option value="276">Cold chai</option><option value="275">Hot chai</option><option value="277">Shakes</option>

Comment: This is my response@JensonMJohn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `append()` or `html()` instead of `val()`

also you do not have a `div.sub` element in the code you've shown us, so I assume you want to add the response to the second select tag:

```
function getSubCategory(){
    var catId = $("#type").val();
    ajax(url,{id:catId,action:"getAllSubcategory"},function (response){
        $("#sub_type").append(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amin jafari. Its woking like anything.

Comment: i think empty before append will be appropriate right... @Amin Jafari

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi you're right, but I think if the response must be added multiple times then html should be used